# NoClassDefFoundError and Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I am using the code from Rome's tutorials page http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome05TutorialFeedReader .    Also trying this one: http://wiki.java.net/twiki/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome05TutorialFeedReader

Compiling works, but I'm not sure how to run these examples.  Why I just type `java FeedReader` or `java FeedAggregator` into the command line, I get the error:

```
C:\projects\freshmeat\src>java FeedAggregator http://freecode.com/?format=atom
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/syndication/f
eed/synd/SyndFeed
```

plus the large block that follows this error

Why is this happening, how do I fix it and try these things out?   How do I get something to work with Rome!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include rome in the runtime classpath (in addition to the compile-time classpath)

```
java -classpath lib/rome.jar FeedAggregator ...
```

Comment: I did include rome in my classpath.  here is my compile command: `C:\projects\freshmeat\src>javac -cp c:\projects\freshmeat\libs\rome-1.0.jar;c:\p
rojects\freshmeat\libs\jdom-1.0.jar FeedAggregator.java`

Comment: this is the compile-time classpath. You have to include it in the runtime classpath as well

Comment: Thanks.  Ok, now I get this:`C:\projects\freshmeat\src>java -cp c:\projects\freshmeat\libs\rome-1.0.jar;c:\pr
ojects\freshmeat\libs\jdom-1.0.jar FeedAggregator
Error: Could not find or load main class FeedAggregator`

Comment: no more ideas?  Thanks for the help so far, I am a complete beginner

Comment: this means your .class is not found. You usually run the program from /bin, rather than from /src

Comment: You must not only put the Rome JAR in the classpath, but also the directory or JAR file that contains your `FeedAggregator` class.

Answer (score 0):

The samples you are trying to run are in the package `com.sun.syndication.samples`.  You say you are a complete beginner, so, to make things simpler, I would recommend that you remove the line beginning with `package` in each of `FeedReader.java` and `FeedAggregator.java`.  Recompile the classes after removing their `package` directives.

Then, to run these classes, make sure you're in the same directory as the class files `FeedReader.class` and `FeedAggregator.class` that `javac` created. Then, try running:

```
java -cp c:\projects\freshmeat\libs\rome-1.0.jar;c:\projects\freshmeat\libs\jdom-1.0.jar;. FeedReader
```

(and similarly for `FeedAggregator`.)

Note also that I've added the current directory, `.`, to the `-cp` attribute.  Without this, the Java virtual machine won't know that it has to look in the current directory to find your `FeedReader` and `FeedAggregator` classes.

If you were to reinstate the `package` directives, you'd find the class files `FeedReader.class` and `FeedAggregator.class` would be created inside a directory `com\sun\syndication\samples` when you compile their sources.  To run the class files from this location, you'd use a command line such as

```
java -cp c:\projects\freshmeat\libs\rome-1.0.jar;c:\projects\freshmeat\libs\jdom-1.0.jar;. com.sun.syndication.samples.FeedReader
```

and you'd run this from the directory containing the `com` subdirectory, not the directory that contains the class files.

More information on packages in Java can be found [here](http://javaworkshop.sourceforge.net/chapter3.html#Java+Packages).